# Why we get "undefined" in the first render via props after a call in a redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example:
I have a application that do a axios call in the action:

```
export function search (name) {
  const request = axios.get(`${NEW_URL}`)
  return {
    type: NEW_SEARCH,
    payload: newRequest
  }
}
```

Then when this is executed by my App for example:

```
componentWillMount () {
  this.props.search('example')
}
```

The console.log gets undefined for the first rendering, example:

```
render () {
  let poster = this.props.movie
  console.log(poster)
}
```

So It breaks the application if I need a property inside the object returned as it is undefined, example:

```
let poster = this.props.movie.movie_path
```

But this works with a little trick adding the || {}

```
render() {
let poster_path = this.props.movie.poster_path || {}
```

What is the logic?

The reducer:

```
case NEW_SEARCH:
  return { ...state, newMovie: action.payload.data }
```

I'm using the redux-promise middleware, if it helps to understand something

My question is: Why I get this undefined that I need to add " || {} " for the first render, then after that I get the object correctly?

Comment: `let {poster_path} = this.props.movie` is same as `let poster_path = this.props.movie.poster_path` so problem is not in deconstructor, add your reducer code

Comment: You are right, I noticed that to dont break I was using the little trick of:        
     let poster = this.props.newMovie || {}
     let {poster_path} = this.props.newMovie || {}

Comment: I updated the main thread. What i cannot understand is, why Im not receiving the this.props from redux with the information done, and getting undefined for the first rendering